# What does "that" refer to in "... partnership between the workforce and management THAT continually focuses..."?

Tags: clauses

> IHTIMAM is a process **that** creates a safety partnership between the workforce and management **that** continually focuses everyone's attention and actions on their own and others daily safety behavior.

My question is that there are two bold **that**s above and the first one define to process but I am confused about the second one which is after the management above define to what? Please clarify.

Comment: This is a clumsy sentence, but it probably refers to "partnership".

Comment: IHTIMAM is a process that creates [a partnership that focuses everyone's attention on safety behavior].

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a mistake in the use of the objective pronoun *others* when the possessive pronoun *others'* should be used instead.

> IHTIMAM is a process **that** creates a safety partnership between the workforce and management **that** continually focuses everyone's attention and actions on their own and [others'] daily safety behavior.

The first *that-clause* is a restrictive relative clause modifying *process*; the second, modifying *partnership*.